How can I convert an INTERVAL datatype to DATETIME or TIMESTAMP
I'm trying to calculate the subtraction of two columns(started_at & ended_at) with datatypes of TIMESTAMP but the result comes out as INTERVAL datatype. How can I convert the result datatype from INTERVAL to TIMESTAMP or TIME etc.
SELECT 
  member_casual,
 AVG(trip_duration) AS avg_trip_duration,
 EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM trip_duration) AS dayofweek


FROM(
  SELECT
  member_casual,
  ended_at - started_at AS trip_duration
  FROM `helical-fin-439209-b4.cyclistic.202201_tripdata`)


GROUP BY member_casual,trip_duration
ORDER BY avg_trip_duration DESC;

Because trip_duration is INTERVAL datatype I can't extract the DAYOFWEEK from it.
How can I fix this?

You have a big conceptual problem with this.  You took two dates, subtracted them, and got a 'distance' in days between those two dates.  While there IS  a day of week for both your started_at & ended_at dates, that distance between them does NOT have a day of the week.  That is why subtracting two dates results in an INTERVAL - it's a fundamentally different data type and cannot be directly converted to a date.  That is meaningless.  You can only add/subtract intervals to other dates and themselves.

I agree with what @chris mentioned, difference between two days will not have a dayOfWeek.

If I told you it took me 6 hours to run between two towns, what day of the week would that be? It doesn't even make sense to ask the question.
